# how to send data through context in react

Tags: reactjs

while I am sending roles through context, it rendering before updating state( i mean before getting the response from the API). Can any help me how to render context after API response is updated via setState. Thanks in advance

```js
import React, { Component, createContext } from "react";
import AppContext from './context';
import axios from '../../global/config'
class ContextProvider extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      roles: [],
    };
    
  }

 
    getAllroles(){
      axios.get('roles')
      .then(response => {         
            this.setState({roles:response.data.data})        
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
          }) 
      }
     

  componentWillMount() {
    this.getAllroles();
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <AppContext.Provider value={{posts: this.state}}>
        {this.props.children}
       </AppContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default ContextProvider;
```

Comment: try to put this.getAllroles(); in componentDidMount method, and add a condition in render function, which will check the state for emptyness

Comment: @rgen3, thanks for the response but i tried componentDidMount and if condition  also it is not working

Comment: may be this way it will work, try to replace `() => {}` for `function () {}` in `then` method and put everything in componentDidMount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context `Provider` isn't any different than any other component that is asynchronously rendered. Components should be [conditionally rendered](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator) with short-circuit evaluation.

It's either:

```js
return !!this.state && (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{posts: this.state}}>
    {this.props.children}
   </AppContext.Provider>
);
```

Or:

```js
return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{posts: this.state}}>
    {this.state && this.props.children}
   </AppContext.Provider>
);
```

Comment: thanks for the response, I tried the above code. the problem is if I refresh a page where I can use context.Consumer,posts are rendering before API response. initially, it was fine the problem was with refresh only

Comment: If I understood the problem correctly, you don't need to set initial state then, `this.state = {
      roles: [],
    }`. `!!this.state` should be false when children shouldn't be rendered. If it's only about posts, then the condition should be changed from `this.state` to `this.state.posts` everywhere.